# Choosing names for null or missing objects

Tags: design-patterns

The Null Object pattern are a great tool for test driven development.  If I need to make the behavior of a system more complex, I introduce a null object so that I get back to green quickly.  Also, often the null object is useful to keep around for the purposes of old unit tests.  More information and other uses of the null object pattern are here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Now that I have a few of these in the system I am beginning to wonder about the best way to name these.  Do you typically just put Null as the first word in the name, or do you give each null object its own name?

Let me setup an example for the purposes of discussion.  Let's say I used to wear nothing but black turtlenecks but now I want to vary my wardrobe a bit.  I'll call my new type a WardrobeChooser.  To encapsulate the old behavior, I could call my old object NullWardrobeChooser or BlackTurtleneckWardrobeChooser or even MissingWardrobeChooser (yikes!  that one could be bad).  What name would you recommend?

I looked on the web, but I can't seem to find any references about this.

Comment: The naming convention you choose is up to you (and your team).  So long as you're consistent, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: +1 to Oli; it's arbitrary. That said, `Null` has a fairly specific semantic meaning; I'll prefix with `Default` or `Empty` when the object represents things like "unsaved" or "not logged in" etc. This introduces a modicum of inconsistency, but I'd rather have *semantic* consistency.

Comment: Alternatively, `BlackTurtleneckWardrobeChooser` is _contextually semantic_, because in your example, the null object actually performs some action (i.e. the side-effect of using it is to always choose black turtlenecks).

Comment: Thanks Dave and cbuckley!  I think I will go with semantic names (i.e. BlackTurtleneckWardrobeChooser)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I prefer not to use naming strategies for null objects and name them according to the behavior their expose.

In case that it takes time to come up with convenient naming I think that prefixes like `Empty` or `Default` are better than `Null` cause it just tells that *null object pattern* is used and nothing else.

Some examples of names for Null Objects are: `NoDiscount`, `EmptyIterator`, `DefaultPaymentStrategy`, etc.